# SQL Server concurrency issue while transaction amount real time limit validation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have transaction table like below where transaction entry will insert and after that validation is happening for transaction such as no account number perform transaction more than 5000 ( 5K) in a day.

Now in below scenario both the transaction will process successfully as its comes from different session via API in same time.

| tranid | Amount | AccountNumber | TrnTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5000 | 12345 | 2021-01-31 20:20:57.713 |
| 1002 | 2000 | 12345 | 2021-01-31 20:20:57.713 |

SQL query in the stored procedure:

```
select sum(Amount) 
from tblTransaction with(nolock)
where DebitAccount = '12345' 
  and month(TrnTime) = month(getdate())
```

I removed `with(nolock)` but query performance is very slow. This table contains more than 10 million records and same time almost 100 transactions coming per millisecond so I have restriction on removing no lock which will create locking/delay in other transaction processing.

Comment: _more than 5000 ( 5K) in a day._ and _month(TrnTime) = month(getdate())_ do not match. Your question needs clarification. But it is almost a certainty that you and your peers do not fully understand what nolock does. Do you want data that is correct? [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) is not your friend, is not a best practice, and should rarely be used. More importantly - what is the issue you are trying to address? Transaction processing speed, your constraint logic, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your query slowness is almost certainly down to :

1. Lack of suitable indexes to quickly find the associated rows
2. The function being applied to the `TrnTime` column - forcing a table scan

If you create an additional calculated column for `MONTH(TrnTime)` and include that in a non-clustered index with `Amount` and `DebitAccount` then your query would be quicker.

Also,  calculating a balance (which I assume you are by calculating the sum of amounts on an account) while using `NOLOCK` is full of dangers through phantom reads and repeated reads so I would not trust those query results.

With the size of the table, also consider partitioning it - either by `MONTH(TrnTime)` or by `DebitAccount` columns

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing this query as:

```
select sum(Amount) 
from tblTransaction
where DebitAccount = 12345 and
      trntime >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

I am guessing that there are no future transactions, so you don't have to check for that.  Also, `DebitAccount` looks like a number.  If it is really a string, then use single quotes.

Then, for this query, you want an index on `tblTransaction(DebitAccount, trnTime, Amount)`.